# how to show custom modal or error modal using react context with dynamic messages?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

could you please tell me 
how to show custom modal or error modal using react context with **dynamic messages ?**

I tried like this
https://codesandbox.io/s/sleepy-wozniak-3be3j

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
import ErrorContext from "./context";

const ErrorProvider = ({ children }) => {
  /**
   * Loading state/controls
   */

  const showErrorPopUp = () => {
    toggleErrorModal(prevState => {
      return {
        ...prevState,
        showError: true
      };
    });
  };

  const hideErrorPopUp = () => {
    toggleErrorModal(prevState => {
      return {
        ...prevState,
        showError: false
      };
    });
  };

  const errorPopUpState = {
    showError: true,
    showErrorPopUp,
    hideErrorPopUp
  };

  const [loading, toggleErrorModal] = useState(errorPopUpState);

  return (
    <ErrorContext.Provider value={loading}>{children}</ErrorContext.Provider>
  );
};

export default ErrorProvider;
```

**can we show Error modal with a dynamic message using react context**

```
function App() {
  const { showErrorPopUp, hideErrorPopUp } = useContext(ErrorContext);

  return <div className="App">{showErrorPopUp()}</div>;
}
```

I am getting this error

**Maximum update depth exceeded. This can happen when a component repeatedly calls setState inside componentWillUpdate or componentDidUpdate. React limits the number of nested updates to prevent infinite loops**

how to send dynamic message in this modal ?

Comment: First of all, thank you for providing the runnable code. It was easy to take a look at what's going on.

Other's already answered the question so I've forked your sandbox to implement it.  Just typesomething in the input, for the message, and click `Show Modal`. 
 https://codesandbox.io/s/soanswer57525151-cyevw  I used Context API, and refer to Kent C. Dodd's post [How to use React Context effectively](https://kentcdodds.com/blog/how-to-use-react-context-effectively)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are making recursive calls with showErrorPopUp. Let me explain what is going on with your code:

You are rendering App which calls showErrorPopUp which handles state. Because you are handling state, component is updating, which means it will rerender App which calls showErrorPopUp,...and this is repeating until the application breaks.

For further details on how to work with hooks and ContextAPI, read this [article](https://blog.ryukote.io/2019/08/15/react-hooks/) which will give you insights on what should you do with useEffect and useContext.

Comment: I got it can you help me making this custom error pop up with dynamic message

Comment: First read the article and try to understand how hooks and Context API works and after that try to figure out yourself. If you got stuck, come here with code that you wrote and I will help you.

Comment: ok ...!!  I will read ..could you please check one time my updated code..https://codesandbox.io/s/sleepy-wozniak-3be3j

Comment: Sure thing. Just write a comment here and I will get a notification.

Comment: I got your point,..I refactor my code but still my error pop up not display

Comment: i used useEffect to call first time but still not display

Answer (score 0):

Let me tell you what is going on.

Whenever you change `state`, it rerenders the component. So when you do the recursive call, you start with `state`, change it, and then it repeats again and rerenders and rerenders until the app breaks, sending a error message.

Comment: https://codesandbox.io/s/sleepy-wozniak-3be3j see error pop not display

Comment: Then I don't know.

Comment: i used `useEffect` to call first time but still not display

Comment: I got your point,..I refactor my code but still my error pop up not display

Comment: Then, I will tell you, why do you need dynamic messages. When I make error responders, I always use `window.confirm()`.